# Bootstrap tooltip with data-html and box2dweb

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this weird bug. If I add box2dweb to my list of javascripts. My bootstrap tooltip will no longer accept HTML. I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
   <button class="btn-sm btn-primary col" id="btn-test" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title="<font size='30'>Tooltip</font> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">Test</button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/box2d.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
   })
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't render the HTML in the tooltip as HTML. But if I remove the script line which is embeding box2dweb it will work.

Is there a way to fix this?

Box2DWeb: [Github](https://github.com/hecht-software/box2dweb)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/box2d.min.js"></script>
```

in `<head>` tag

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
              $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
            })
</script>
```

outside `<body>` tag.